# FFMPEG stop working with no error

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, transcode

I am using FFMPEG to create a video using pictures as input. I never had a problem with it, but now for some jobs I can't get correct outputs, some of them are broken.

Using FFPROBE to check the output file I have next informations:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2697ba0] moov atom not found
pc3.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The command line it seems is to bigger for the body of the question.

This is the output of the FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg version N-79052-g03a6ed8-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint --enable-libvpx --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfontconfig
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.103 / 57. 28.103
  libavformat    57. 28.101 / 57. 28.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/seanhe_family_cartoon.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7217 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 306x192, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #1, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2014_01_19_2_078.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13236 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 384x512 [SAR 96:96 DAR 3:4], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #2, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/IMG_20141201_160830.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 612285 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2448x3264, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #3, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2014_01_19_2_086.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11589 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 512x384 [SAR 96:96 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #4, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2015_03_06_037.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 778262 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4320x3240, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #5, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2015_07_15_002.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1296466 kb/s
    Stream #5:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #6, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2015_07_15_028.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1007659 kb/s
    Stream #6:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #7, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01310.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1875398 kb/s
    Stream #7:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #8, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01323.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2374326 kb/s
    Stream #8:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x15e5860] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #9, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01327.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #9:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x1f9c480] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #10, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01344.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #10:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #11, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01350.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2131379 kb/s
    Stream #11:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #12, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01370.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1688512 kb/s
    Stream #12:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #13, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01419.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1490661 kb/s
    Stream #13:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #14, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01421.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1439411 kb/s
    Stream #14:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x15faf80] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #15, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01508.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #15:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x15fd120] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #16, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01510.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #16:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #17, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/Nexus5_2015_01_19_061.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 473797 kb/s
    Stream #17:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3264x2448, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #18, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/2015_07_15_018.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1622789 kb/s
    Stream #18:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #19, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_005.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1767829 kb/s
    Stream #19:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #20, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_034.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1637301 kb/s
    Stream #20:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #21, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_112.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1643462 kb/s
    Stream #21:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #22, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_131.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1410111 kb/s
    Stream #22:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #23, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_136.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1387803 kb/s
    Stream #23:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj440p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3672x4896 [SAR 350:350 DAR 3:4], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #24, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_140.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1162364 kb/s
    Stream #24:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #25, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_149.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1590499 kb/s
    Stream #25:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #26, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_156.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1103223 kb/s
    Stream #26:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #27, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_164.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1397964 kb/s
    Stream #27:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #28, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_170.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1505306 kb/s
    Stream #28:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #29, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_175.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1336799 kb/s
    Stream #29:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj440p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3672x4896 [SAR 350:350 DAR 3:4], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #30, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_223.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1226608 kb/s
    Stream #30:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj440p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3672x4896 [SAR 350:350 DAR 3:4], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #31, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_232.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1300989 kb/s
    Stream #31:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #32, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_365.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1276539 kb/s
    Stream #32:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj440p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3672x4896 [SAR 350:350 DAR 3:4], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #33, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_373.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1389901 kb/s
    Stream #33:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #34, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/algonquin_415.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1021508 kb/s
    Stream #34:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #35, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/july2015_005.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1189976 kb/s
    Stream #35:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #36, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/july2015_008.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2027852 kb/s
    Stream #36:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #37, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/july2015_009.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1546779 kb/s
    Stream #37:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #38, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/july2015_024.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1455708 kb/s
    Stream #38:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #39, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/marine_land_006.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1058776 kb/s
    Stream #39:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #40, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/marine_land_010.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1055506 kb/s
    Stream #40:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #41, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/marine_land_124.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 997881 kb/s
    Stream #41:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #42, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01594.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1765197 kb/s
    Stream #42:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #43, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01601.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2164621 kb/s
    Stream #43:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #44, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01602.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1853271 kb/s
    Stream #44:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #45, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01616.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1585490 kb/s
    Stream #45:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #46, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01619.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1749801 kb/s
    Stream #46:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #47, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01623.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1241637 kb/s
    Stream #47:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #48, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01638.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1839170 kb/s
    Stream #48:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #49, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01645.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1544173 kb/s
    Stream #49:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0xeb50260] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #50, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01875.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #50:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0xeb51ee0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #51, png_pipe, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01881.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #51:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3672x4895, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #52, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01889.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1136646 kb/s
    Stream #52:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #53, image2, from '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/DSC01652.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1127971 kb/s
    Stream #53:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4896x3672, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #54, lavfi, from 'color=black':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #54:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_amovie_0 @ 0xeb91880] Channel layout is not set in output stream 0, guessed channel layout is 'stereo'
Input #55, lavfi, from 'amovie=/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/sox_processed_normal_234018_audio.wav':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 512 kb/s
    Stream #55:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 16000 Hz, stereo, s16, 512 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0x2b1b740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2b28280] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2b34dc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2b64600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2b8d3a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2c13000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2ca3340] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xf01dce0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xf0ae920] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xf3773e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x13c70960] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x13d016c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x13d92300] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1405adc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x140b06c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x145bcaa0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1464d740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x146de420] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1476f140] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x147fff20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14877ec0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14908b80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14999480] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14a2a620] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14abb260] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14b4c060] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14bc4080] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14c3c1c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14cccd20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14d44d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14dd5b00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14e66440] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14ef7380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x14f88180] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x15018e40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x150a96c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1513a4a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x151cb500] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1525c1a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x152ecfa0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1537d600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1540e420] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1549f3c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x155301c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x155c0e80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x15651600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1591a220] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x159ab260] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0xc9f4ac0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xc9f4ac0] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xc9f4ac0] profile Main, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0xc9f4ac0] 264 - core 148 r2665 a01e339 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=120 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=800 vbv_bufsize=1600 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/tsops/uploads/234018_web/master_output/pc3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libfaac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 16000 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.103 libfaac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=10-51, 800 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.103 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 800000/0/800000 buffer size: 1600000 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #4:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #5:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #6:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #7:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #8:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #9:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #10:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #11:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #12:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #13:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #14:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #15:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #16:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #17:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #18:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #19:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #20:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #21:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #22:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #23:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #24:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #25:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #26:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #27:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #28:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #29:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #30:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #31:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #32:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #33:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #34:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #35:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #36:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #37:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #38:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #39:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #40:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #41:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #42:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #43:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #44:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #45:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #46:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #47:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #48:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #49:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #50:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #51:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #52:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #53:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #54:0 (rawvideo) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #55:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (libfaac))
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x2b0ec00] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[user]# s=5.2 q=22.0 size=   33072kB time=00:05:55.32 bitrate= 762.5kbits/s speed=0.171x
```

The output file should have at least 6 minutes, but the process stops before he finish it.

Can somebody give me a clue or a solution to this ?

Thank you!

Comment: The command have for input 54 pictures, 1 black background, 1 audio resource and is sent with following options: -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -ab "96k" -ac 2 -map 55:0 -map "[outv]" -t 378 -vprofile main -movflags faststart -preset medium -b:v 800k -minrate 500k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 1600k -g 120 -refs 2 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -i_qfactor 0.71 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method umh -pix_fmt yuv420p -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)'

Comment: Show the full command. The console shows that encoding occured till 5m55s atleast.

Comment: The command is to big because I do a lot of filtering, I encoded at least 1k jobs without a problem. What you need to know from the command ?

Comment: Error or warning messages. Use `-report` and link to the log.

Comment: By the way, is this an error or warning  Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize

Comment: For an image input, no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39469/discussion-between-rducanu-ionu-and-mulvya).

Comment: Can we start a discussion please ? I have more details and I need an accurate conversation. Thank you!